# How to use input filename to generate output filename with Rake?

Tags: ruby, scripting, rake

I've got some input files which I want to encode using Ruby. The output from the encoding should match some pattern based on the filename of the input file. In order to not do this by hand, I want to use Rake as help for automation. Further I'd like to not specify a single task for every input file.

I've tried some FileList "magic" but it didn't work out. Here's the code:

```
desc 'Create all output from specified input'
task :encode do
  FileList['input/*.txt'].each {|input| file "output/output_#{input}" => input}
end
```

Anyone can help? I didn't find find anything on the web about multiple output files as dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using Rake's `rule` tasks, which allow tasks to be dynamically defined based on regex rules. See the [rakefile rdoc](http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) page for details, but here's an example:

```
# creates the 'output' directory on demand
directory "output"

# define a task rule covering all the output files
rule %r{output/output_} => ['output', proc {|task_name| "input/#{task_name.sub('output/output_', '')}.txt"}] do |t|
  # replace this with your encoding logic
  sh "echo 'file #{t.source}' > #{t.name}"
end

# define a top-level 'encode' task which depends on all the 'output/output_*' tasks
task :encode => Dir['input/*.txt'].map {|x| "output/output_#{File.basename(x).sub('.txt', '')}"}
```

And then you should be able to run `rake encode` in a directory with files matching `input/*`, and have the output files be placed in `output/output_*`.

Comment: Thx! Worked a wonder. I found out about rules, but didn't really get how to trigger them. You got a nice example.