# How To Process Inputs and Outputs in Separate Directories in Rake?

Tags: rake

I am trying to convert Haml files to HTML files using Rake, so that if the Haml files have not changed, I do not re-generate existing HTML.

However, I do not want my input files, output files, and `Rakefile` all smushed into one directory. Instead, I want my input files to be in `src/` and my output files to be in `build/output/`. So, I want to start with:

```
Rakefile
src/
  slides.haml
```

and I want to end with:

```
Rakefile
src/
  slides.haml
build/
  output/
    slides.html
```

I have tried several bits of Rake code, with no luck.

First, I tried the caveman approach, hard-coding the precise files I am trying:

```
task "build/output/slides.html" => "src/slides.haml" do
  touch task.name
end

task :slides => "src/slides.haml"
task :default => "slides"
```

Running `rake --trace` results in:

```
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke slides (first_time)
** Invoke src/slides.haml (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute slides
** Execute default
```

The directory is not built, and I do not have an empty `build/output/slides.html` file.

Ideally, I'd prefer a `rule`-and-`FileList` approach, using stuff like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493501/how-to-use-input-filename-to-generate-output-filename-with-rake) or [this "Rake cheatshet" entry](http://software.clapper.org/cheat-sheets/rake.html). However, I tried a few variations on that theme, and I get the same results, suggesting that I have something more profoundly messed up. I have trimmed my `Rakefile` back to the caveman approach, just to try to grok what's going on here.

Why is Rake not recognizing my `"build/output/slides.html"` task? Is there some magic to using subdirectories (input or output) in Rake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing that file tasks use `file` instead of `task`, and that there is a `directory` task as well.

The working version of the caveman approach is:

```
namespace :build do
  directory "build/output"

  file "build/output/slides.html" => ["build/output", "src/slides.haml"] do |t|
    touch t.name
  end

  task :all => "build/output/slides.html"
end

task :default => ['build:all']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I put together today that I believe accomplishes the same thing you were trying to accomplish. First, I define `mv_rule` (can be in a separate ruby file that you `import`/`require`), then define a `directory` task for the output directory, and finally make a rule that describes the output pattern (including directory) and input pattern (including directory).

```
# Declare a rule for auto-tasks that have input and output in different directories
#
# Example:
#  mv_rule 'obj/*.o' => 'src/*.c' do |t|
#    sh "gcc -c #{t.source} -o #{t.name}"
#
def mv_rule(*args, &block) # :doc:
  outFile, inFile = args[0].keys[0], args[0].values[0]
  outExt = File.extname outFile
  outDir = File.dirname outFile
  inExt = File.extname inFile
  inDir = File.dirname inFile
  destPattern = Regexp.new("#{outDir}/.*\\#{outExt}")
  srcPattern = ->(o){o.pathmap("%{^#{outDir}/,#{inDir}/}X#{inExt}")}
  Rake::Task.create_rule(destPattern => [srcPattern, outDir], &block)
end

directory "build/output"

mv_rule 'build/output/*.html' => 'src/*.haml' do |t|
    touch t.name
end

task :all => "build/output/slides.html"

task :default => [:all]
```

I can run it with `rake` to execute the `:default` task. Or, since I specified a general rule for making `html` from `haml` in the appropriate directories, I can run it with `rake build/output/more_slides.html` (assuming there's a `src/more_slides.haml`).

I kind of surprised there isn't a built-in way to specify a different output directory. It seems like a pretty common scenario.

I made my `mv_rule` to make a general solution to the problem with a pretty straight-forward syntax. It probably has limitations I haven't even thought about, yet.  I used http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/04/23/rake-part-3-rules/ and http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/04/24/rake-part-4-pathmap/ for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, tasks are declared as `task :name => dependency`. Your `:slides` task names a source instead of an output dependency. Also, your `:default` task depends on a file `"slides"` instead of the task `:slides`. Change those lines to be

```
task :slides => "build/output/slides.html"
task :default => :slides
```

Next, the block of code that will actually execute should be a rule, not a task, and you can access the internal information of the rule via `#{t.<param>}`:

```
rule "build/output/slides.html" => "src/slides.html" do |t|
  sh "mkdir -p $(dirname #{t.name})"
  sh "touch #{t.name}"
end
```

There are better ways of making the rule more generic, building up lists of source files and mapping them to outputs, etc. Some useful tutorials are here https://github.com/ruby/rake#presentations-and-articles-about-rake

There are probably also more Ruby-esque ways of making the `build/output/` directory if it does not exist, rather than invoking a shell to do it.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll grant you the bounty, mostly because you triggered me (while trying to make sense of where I was going wrong with respect to your answer) to notice exactly where my caveman approach had gone awry.

Answer (score 0):

The non-caveman tool for this job is `pathmap`.

```rb
SOURCES = FileList['src/*.haml']

directory 'build/output'

rule '.html' do |t|
  sh 'touch', t.name
end

task :default => ['build/output', SOURCES.pathmap('build/output/%n.html')]
```

Output:

```
$ mkdir src && touch src/slides.haml
$ rake --trace
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke build/output (first_time)
** Execute build/output
mkdir -p build/output
** Invoke build/output/slides.html (first_time)
** Execute build/output/slides.html
touch build/output/slides.html
** Execute default
```

For this kind of task, you might also be interested in `rake/clean` for generating tasks to restore your project to a pristine state:

```rb
require 'rake/clean'
CLOBBER.include 'build' # running 'rake clobber' will remove the build directory
```

- https://quix.github.io/rake/classes/String.html#method-i-pathmap
- http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/04/24/rake-part-4-pathmap/
- https://ruby.github.io/rake/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-Clean+and+Clobber+Tasks